# jQuery UI Dialog box only opens once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Each dialog box only opens once, after that nothing happens.  I've searched for a while and there are a few answers in regards to this here but I honestly don't understand them. (I'm quite new to jQuery and jQuery UI)  So any help you can give me would be great!

**http://jsfiddle.net/bf44crt0/**

```
$('.prdDetails').click(function() {
        $(this).next('#prdDetails').dialog({
            draggable: false,
            height: 100,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 100
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Two things. First, IDs **must** be unique. Second, jQuery UI will change the order of your DOM elements so don't rely on `.next()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in that line:

```
$(this).next('#prdDetails').dialog({
```

The dialog changes its position after it's opened, therefore it's not anymore `next()` to the opener.

You should identify dialogs with **unique** `id`'s.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="prdDetails" data-dialog="#d1">Dialog 1</a>
<div id="d1" class="hidden">This Is Dialog 1</div>

<a class="prdDetails" data-dialog="#d2">Dialog 2</a>
<div id="d2" class="hidden">This Is Dialog 2</div>

<a class="prdDetails" data-dialog="#d3">Dialog 3</a>
<div id="d3" class="hidden">This Is Dialog 3</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$('.prdDetails').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this).data('dialog')).dialog({
        draggable: false,
        height: 100,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: 100
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yj4ga6p/)** (open console to get the idea what is happening with the dialogs, and why you cannot use `next()`)

Comment: This isn't the method I chose to use but thank you for your help!  I didn't understand that the dialog position moved.  I simply thought it was destroyed!  I was much less confused after that!